# Group BY on Condition basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in following way....

```
ColumnA ColumnB
7675    22838
7675    24907
7675    NULL
```

I want the results in following way.....

```
ColumnA ColumnB
7675    2  (need total count for Not Null value)
7675    0  (need count 0 for NULL value)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT ColumnA, COUNT(ColumnB) ColumnB
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ColumnA
UNION ALL
SELECT ColumnA, 0
FROM YourTable
WHERE ColumnB IS NULL
GROUP BY ColumnA
```

Comment: @evanv Because that wouldn't return the result set that op wants

Comment: I did not notice that the column A values were identical. Yes, Lamak is exactly correct on this point.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a calculated column indicating whether `ColumnB` is null or not and use it as a grouping criterion together with `ColumnA`:

```
SELECT
  t.ColumnA,
  ColumnB = COUNT(t.ColumnB)
FROM
  dbo.YourTable AS t
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CASE WHEN t.ColumnB IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS x (SubGroup)
GROUP BY
  t.ColumnA,
  x.SubGroup
ORDER BY
  t.ColumnA,
  x.SubGroup
;
```

The `COUNT(t.ColumnB)` expression would always be NULL for a null subgroup, and for the corresponding non-null subgroup it would return the number of the non-null entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select columnA, 
       count(columnB) as non_null_count, 
       sum(columnB is null) as null_count
from your_table
group by ColumnA
```

Comment: I like the way you are separating null and non null counts into different columns... this will not yield the result @jitendra requested, but it arguably is a better result than the one he s/he had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

you could easily do with a count and sum which may be faster if there are a lot of rows rather than selecting all of the rows twice with a UNION

```
SELECT columna, columnb, SUM(mycount) 
FROM
(   SELECT *, COUNT(columnb) as mycount 
    FROM test
    GROUP BY columnb
)t
GROUP BY mycount
ORDER BY CASE WHEN mycount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END DESC;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e40ada/1)